# How to pass multiple regexpression extracted values to a single http request?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am sending First request to server: 
POST http://192.168.7.101/r2.web/Planning/Scheduling/TimelinefromR3 -->**(A)**

I have written Regular Expression extractor(`(?<=\"Values":")(.*?)(?=\")`) to extract Resourcenames like "Ray Gwilliams" and "James Mark" from the response of **(A)**,

Now, I have another request(as mentioned below) to which, I need to pass all the Resource names("Ray Gwilliams" and "James Mark") extracted above.

> Please let me know how to achieve this.

http://192.168.7.101/R2.Web/Planning/Scheduling/SchedulesAndGroups

POST data:
[{"ColumnName":"CONTACTNAME","ColumnIId":0,"UdfIId":null,"ConditionIId":0,"OperatorIId":1,"SequenceNo":0,"Values":"**Ray Gwilliams**
","Lookup":null,"LookupIId":0,"LookupSource":0,"LookupType":0,"MultipleOperatorIIds":null,"MultipleValues":null,"ColumnDataType":null},{"ColumnName":"CONTACTNAME","ColumnIId":0,"UdfIId":null,"ConditionIId":0,"OperatorIId":1,"SequenceNo":0,"Values":"**James Mark**
","Lookup":null,"LookupIId":0,"LookupSource":0,"LookupType":0,"MultipleOperatorIIds":null,"MultipleValues":null,"ColumnDataType":null}

Comment: Do you really need regex for this? That looks like a JSON.  So [using a json parser](https://jmetervn.com/2016/09/17/json-path-postprocessor-in-jmeter/) could be a more sturdy approuch.

Comment: UNCLEAR. Is it a regex problem? (prefer using a json parser) or is about "how to pass argument to your http post request"?  or "how to manipulates lists"? or....?

Comment: I will try Jason parser as suggested. However, Iam not clear on how to use the captured data(in the variable using regex) into my http post request. If you can throw some details around that, will certainly help.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the regular expression but if you use the JSON Extractor element and put the extracted value into a variable, you would just add the variable into the 2nd POST request.  For example:

```
POST data:     
[{"ColumnName":"CONTACTNAME",
"ColumnIId":0,"UdfIId":null,"ConditionIId":0,
"OperatorIId":1,"SequenceNo":0,
"Values":"${variable1} ","Lookup":null,"LookupIId":0,
"LookupSource":0,"LookupType":0,
"MultipleOperatorIIds":null,"MultipleValues":null,
"ColumnDataType":null},  {"ColumnName":"CONTACTNAME",
"ColumnIId":0,"UdfIId":null,
"ConditionIId":0,"OperatorIId":1,
"SequenceNo":0,
"Values":"${variable2} ","Lookup":null,"LookupIId":0,
"LookupSource":0,"LookupType":0,
"MultipleOperatorIIds":null,
"MultipleValues":null,"ColumnDataType":null}
```

Tip:  To get the value you want extracted, use jmeter's JSON Path Tester in the View Results in Tree listenter element or this helper tool: http://jsonpath.com/

Comment: Thank you. Iam  finding difficult to extract the value from json response of first request into the variable. Please let me know how do i share my json response with you.

Comment: If you post what is in your response, I may be able to test.  Or past yoru response into http://jsonpath.com and use the helpers there to figure out how to extract the values you want.

Comment: The response is more than the permitted characters here. Please suggest how can I post. I will try it on jsonpath.com in the mean time. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to update your question and include it